# Easy way to cross-compile a Qt application using Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, qt-creator

I'm very new to this C++ and [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) thing, I'm using Qt Creator in Mac OS X.
Is there an easy way to compile for Windows and Linux platform also?
The current way I'm doing is copying the source file to a Windows machine (with Qt) and compile it, which takes a lot of time.

Is there a command or something that can get all 3 executables at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is far from trivial, and [Trolltech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Development_Frameworks#History) didn't like the idea (by making it harder than it should be).

There is *[Cross compiling Qt/Win Apps on Linux](http://silmor.de/29)* on the Internet which will help (only directories might be different for Mac, commands should be the same).

After you have cross-compiled, you'll need to create a shortcut to Qt Creator with a custom PATH that has your cross-compiler directory prepended to the rest of the PATH. That way you can ensure it is used. This is not recommended though.

Why not just use a properly set up VM?

Comment: I will be doing that, I just want an easy solution. Guess it's VMware time.

Comment: Your vmware won't prevent you from having to copy the files : at least, if you use an SCM, you can fix in the VM and push the chanegs to the repository, otherwise, it's hard to follow and reconciliate the changes.

Comment: @Bruce: Virtualbox has the "shared folders" feature (and I'm sure VMWare etc. do too). You can set the source folder to be shared, and work on exactly the same files without copying or anything.

Comment: True. You just have to make sure you don't have end-of-line issue and that you build in different tree, but that could work (although you lose the other benefits of SCM :-) )

Comment: @Bruce: ah yes, `\n` vs `\n\r`. That can be helped around by using the right text editor (notepad++ ftw, or heck even Visual Studio can be set up correctly in this regard, I think)

Answer (score 3):

It's not supported out of the box and you might end up messing between the different flavours

I strongly suggest, for such a goal:

```
- to use either centralised (svn) or distributed (git, hg) SCM
- to use continuus integration with 3 agents, each one in a different platform (can be VM or physical computer).  You can use hudson or cruise control
```

This way:

```
- you develop locally, on whatever platform you prefer
- you push / commit / submit your changes
- the buildbox compiles on all platforms (while you can still work on the next feature)
- ideally, you run your unit tests as well
- once all builds on all platforms are finished, you got a status and a build on all targets
```

This is fairly useful when wanting to deal with more than  one version of Qt or compiler : the return value is definitely worth the time invested in the setup (and it scales well)